# how to to process result of google distance matrix api further?

Tags: api, matrix, distance

i am new to programming.. i have this code which gives distance between two points but need to further multiply it by an  integer say 10.. the project i am working on is abt calculating distance between two points and multiplying it with  fare/Km like Rs.10/km (Indian Rupees) for the same. So if the distance is 30 km the fare would be 30*10 = Rs.300

Thanks in advance

following is the code

```
<script>
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];
  var origin1 = '';
  var destinationA = '';

  var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';

  var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';


function initialize() {
    var opts = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);


var fromText = document.getElementById('FAdd');

var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
    };var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText, options);


fromAuto.bindTo('bound', map);


var toText = document.getElementById('TAdd');

var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText, options);


toAuto.bindTo('bound', map);


    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }

  function calculateDistances() {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [document.getElementById("FAdd").value],
        destinations: [document.getElementById("TAdd").value],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, callback);
  }

  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
      deleteOverlays();


      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        addMarker(origins[i], false);
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          addMarker(destinations[j], true);

        outputDiv.innerHTML += results[j].distance.text  + '<br>'; 

        }
      }
   }
  }

  function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
    var icon;
    if (isDestination) {
      icon = destinationIcon;
    } else {
      icon = originIcon;
    }
    geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          icon: icon
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
          + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function deleteOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
      for (i in markersArray) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
      markersArray.length = 0;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an Ajax call to PHP, and haven't yet used getDistanceMatrix(), but this should be an easy fix. 
First, if you know you will always only have one origin and one destination, you don't need the "for" loop in your callback function. Second, you're taking the distance text rather than the distance value.

```
function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
       [...]
    } else {
        deleteOverlays();
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv'),
            origin = response.originAddresses[0],
            destination = response.destinationAddresses[0],
            result = response.rows[0].elements[0],
            distance = result.distance.value,
            text = result.distance.text,
            price = 10 * distance;
        outputDiv.innerHTML = '<p>' + text + ': Rs.' + price + '</p>';
        addMarker(origin, false);
        addMarker(destination, false);
    }
```

}

I haven't tested this, so it probably needs to be tweaked. ( See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixResponses )